# Using Backbone Rails and am getting a `cannot load such file -- ejs`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, ejs

The backtrace explains nothing :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (cannot load such file -- ejs
  (in /app/assets/javascripts/backbone/templates/questions/connections_game.jst.ejs)):
```

This is really strange because I have two other existing files that are `.jst.ejs` files, and they work *only* if they are named exactly as they are. If I change the spelling from..

```
foobar.jst.ejs
```

to

```
foobar_again.jst.ejs
```

This too will return the same error. If I keep just my two ejs files and not add any new ones, then the app works fine.

There is no content inside my .ejs file.

Comment: can you please paste your view code

Comment: Its an empty file. Same error.

Answer (score 4):

Updating my ejs gem resolved this problem.